# How to refresh a Bean programmatically in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a MyDataSource class annotated with `@Configuration` and it has method returning "HikariDatasource" bean. This method is annotated with `@Bean` as well as `RefreshScoope`.

```
@Configuration
public class MyDataSource {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseProperties databaseProperties;


    @RefreshScope
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(databaseProperties.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setUsername(databaseProperties.getUserName());
        dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(databaseProperties.getConnectionTimeout());
        dataSource.setConnectionInitSql(databaseProperties.getTestConnectionSql());
        dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery(databaseProperties.getTestConnectionSql());
        Log.i("DataSource bean created");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Now, **I have to refresh `dataSource` manually or programmatically from a different class**. And only just need to refresh this bean. It does not automatically gets refreshed even though the refreshScope annotation is there, because the changes are not done in `databaseProperties`.
How do I do this??

I am aware of this method `refresh(beanName)` provided by `@RefreshScope` but not sure how to use it, if it can be used in this scenario??

Comment: what does it mean refresh? why do you need to refresh your poll connection with the same settings?  if you need to get many different connections try receive them on method arguments `dataSource(String  driver, String user , String pass, String url... )` and save them in a `ConcurrentHashMap<String,HikariDataSource>` to use as you need. or if you need to controll the active time connection for each poll you can use all  power of hikari `setMaximumPoolSize`, `setMaxLifetime`, `setIdleTimeout` , `setMinimumIdle` and others. could you explain more about your problem?

Comment: Thanks @DilermandoLima for the info. So, the databaseProperties if refreshed with the new settings, but the dataSource bean is not getting refreshed. I just have to refresh it manually.
I have tired below, but it did not work.

``RefreshScope refreshScope = new RefreshScope();
refreshScope.refreshAll();``